# Macro to create the union of two enums?

Tags: rust, enums, macros, sum-type

And by union I mean the type-theory union of the two sumtypes.

I often find myself creating error types like:

```
enum ErrorA {
  Foo(String),
  Bar(String)
}

enum ErrorB {
  Baz(String),
  Qux(String)
}
```

The two may reside in different modules, or even crates.

I'd like a macro to create either the nested or better, the unnested union of the two:

```
[unionize(ErrorA, ErrorB)]
enum Error
```

I'd like the generated code to generate something like

```
enum Error {
  ErrorA(ErrorA),
  ErrorB(ErrorB)
}

enum Error {
  Foo(String),
  Bar(String),
  Baz(String),
  Qux(String)
}
```

The latter assumes no name collisions between the two variants.
The first is not particularly helpful on its own, it can be written out by hand without too much problems.

The real help would be to generate into implementations from ErrorA and ErrorB into Error, but I don't know how to access their variants, because the macro is defined on Error, so I don't have access to their AST.

Comment: If you're ok with the first alternative for `Error`, perhas you'll find [thiserror](https://docs.rs/thiserror/latest/thiserror/) useful?

Comment: Why not create an enum `enum Error { ErrorA(ErrorA), ErrorB(ErrorB) }`?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73912766/can-a-macro-access-the-field-names-and-types-of-a-remote-struct-from-its-path - This can only be done in any sane manner if you put all three structs into the same macro invocation.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I think I'll stick with `thisError`, although I don't actually need the `std::Error` implementation.